# Add border to divs to look like a table

Tags: css

I need to create two columns which looks like a table with nice 1px border.
Border kills the layout. And is there any nice way how to have nice border with a single line in the middle?

```css
.column-5 { width:50%; float:left; }
.border-light { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zdLdmey/

Comment: Columns? Individually, they look more like rows, if they are considered as a group then column would seem more apropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why adding border "kills" the layout is because **border widths are not taken into account when computing the width** (which uses the `content-box` layout by default). The sum of the width of the two containers will be 50% + 50% + 4px (4 times 1px borders), which exceeds 100%. This causes the second `<div>` element to wrap to the next line.

This can be easily solved by using `box-sizing: border-box`. What this property does is that it forces the width computation to include any border sizes present on the element, such that the inner width plus the border size adds up to the declared width.

```css
.column-5 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  
  /* Force width to take into account border size */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border-light {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an illustration that helps you understand the three different possible values of the `box-sizing` attribute ([source](http://www.cssmine.com/ebook/css3-box-sizing)):

[image: Different box-sizing values]

1. `content-box` (default) does not take into account paddings and borders
2. `padding-box` takes into account paddings only (not what you want)
3. `border-box` takes into account paddings and borders

p/s: None of these box-sizing properties take into account margins, since they are technically *outside* the box.

Comment: This is what I am searching about. Thank you!

Comment: @ManicDepression Glad that the answer helped. I have also added a third-party illustration and additional in-depth explanation about `box-sizing` for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Insert `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.column-5` :

```css
.column-5 {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border-light {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column-5{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.border-light { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right:0; 
}
.border-light:last-child{
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
    column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove border and use outline instead:

```css
.column-5 { width:50%; float:left; }
.border-light { outline: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've demonstrated a few methods you can explore to achieve the intended outcome with the Code Snippet embedded below.

It includes examples which account for more than x2 nested children elements.

Essentially, it comes down to using `pseudo-class` selectors.

> A CSS **pseudo-class** is a keyword added to a selector that specifies a
>   special state of the selected element(s). For example, :hover can be
>   used to change a button's color when the user hovers over it.

**Want to know more?** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

```css
.column-5 { width:50%; float:left; }
.border-light { border: 1px solid black; }

/* Additional */

.column-5:not(:last-child) { /* if .row will only have x2 nested children */
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
/* OR */
.column-5:first-child { /* if .row will only have x2 nested children */
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.many-nested.even .column:nth-child(even) { /* if .row will only more than x2 nested children */
  border-top: 0px;
}
/* OR */
.many-nested.odd .column:nth-child(odd) { /* if .row will only more than x2 nested children */
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

/* Clear floats */

br {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Note: additional classes added purely as demonstration and selector specificity -->
<div class="row many-nested even">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row many-nested odd">
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-5 border-light">
 column 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="column-5 border-light">
        column 1
      </div>
      <div class="column-5 border-light lastRow">
        column 2
      </div>
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
 .column-5{width:50%; float:left;}
    .border-light { 
     border-top: 1px solid black;
     border-left: 1px solid black;
     border-bottom: 0px solid black;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .lastRow { 
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
```